# How to implement the "Shared database, separate schema" multi-tenant strategy

Tags: java, database-design, cloud, saas, multi-tenant

I have to make a web application multi-tenant enabled using Shared database separate schema approach. The application is built using Java/J2EE and Oracle 10g.

I need to have one single appserver using a shared database with multiple schema, one schema per client.

What is the best implementation approach to achieve this?

- What needs to be done at the middle tier (app-server) level?
- Do I need to have multiple host headers each per client?
- How can I connect to the correct schema dynamically based on the client who is accessing the application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177117/saas-multi-tenant-separate-database-model-implementation-in-java

Answer (score 1):

At a high level, here are some things to consider:

- You probably want to hide the tenancy considerations from day-to-day development. Thus, you will probably want to hide it away in your infrastructure as much as possible and keep it separate from your business logic. You don't want to be always checking whether which tenant's context you are in... you just want to be in that context.
- If you are using a unit of work pattern, you will want to make sure that any unit of work (except one that is operating in a purely infrastructure context, not in a business context) executes in the context of exactly one tenant. If you are not using the unit of work pattern... maybe you should be. Not sure how else you are going to follow the advice in the point above  (though maybe you will be able to figure out a way).
- You probably want to put a tenant ID into the header of every messaging or HTTP request. Probably better to keep this out of the body on principle of keeping it away from business logic. You can scrape this off behind the scenes and make sure that behind the scenes it gets put on any outgoing messages/requests.
- I am not familiar with Oracle, but in SQL Server and I believe in Postgres you can use impersonation as a way of switching tenants. That is to say, rather than parameterizing the schema in every SQL command and query, you can just have one SQL user (without an associated login) that has the schema for the associated tenant as its default schema, and then leave the schema out of your day-to-day SQL. You will have to intercept calls to the database and wrap them in an impersonation call. Like I say, I'm not exactly sure how this works out in Oracle, but that's the general idea for SQL Server.
- Authentication and security are a big concern here. That is far beyond the scope of what I can discuss in this answer but *make sure you get that right*.